# setting up my jnlp to run with a specific java path

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

My software has it's own java, using which I have to run my application via `jnlp` through `javaws`. The application requires a certificate which is already imported in it's java. My script-file which is performing the `javaws` call has the following codes:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\my_prog\client\java\jre
set PATH=C:\my_prog\client;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
start C:\my_prog\client\java\jre\bin\javaws -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/my_prog/client/java/jre/lib/security/cacerts -verbose -wait http://localhost:8090/backend/MYClient.jnlp
```

The paths are set to make sure that the `javaws` starts only with the specified java.

The popup from `-verbose` argument shows that `javaws` is starting with the given java and certificate. But when my client starts via JNLP, the clients log is showing System property `java.home` as my Windows local java. As a result, it is failing to validate correct certification when required.

The `java control panel` java settings also shows that it is in the list:

[image]

is there any properties file that the jnlp uses/reads for getting the java path for starting the application? Or is there any way to specify the java.home in the JNLP so that it starts only with the specific java?

Comment: Hmm, can you see *your* java in the java control panel? I don't think you can specify a **JAVA_HOME** for the jnlp, however, I think you can make it download and install a specific JVM that you want used for your program, and so somehow that must also detect that your jvm would already be there (though getting the pre-installed certificates into your distributable then is another thing)

Comment: I see my Client java in the java control panel (see the edit). But ya, the certificate is an issue that still remains even if I download and install it.

Comment: it should somehow be possible to get it either into your package to download/install your java on client's pc _or_ get the client to do it _once_ manually  - the first hurdle is to get the jnlp identify your java. Is there more to it that just using the specific sun version plus the certificate?

Comment: No these are the only two things needed for the application

Answer (score 1):

Try using href attribute of j2se tag..

```
<resources>
    <!-- Application Resources -->
    <j2se version="1.6+" href=
       "some location"/>
 </resources>
```

Not sure of this though!

Comment: sorry but this href is not the physical path of the java the JNLP is supposed to use.